Can contracts be sold as an active?
I was watching this video about Spirit Airlines'troubles.
One of the points is that there was a plan for Jet Blue to buy Spirit, mostly so that Jet Blue could use Spirit's planes (as it seems that supply is not enough for existing orders). Those planes are mostly leased, but with Jet Blue buying (merging with) Spirit, they become the same legal persona and Spirit's contracts become Jet Blue's contracts. That merger was denied by a judge due to anti-competitive issues.
Now, at the end of the video, it tells that with Spirit's bankruptcy proceeds, may Jet Blue will have another opportunity for getting those planes. This is what I have trouble understanding.
On one part, maybe he is refering to Spirit being sold as a whole to Jet Blue. This would be the same than the previous failed merger, and it is clear how it would work. Of course maybe it is blocked again on the same issues, but that is not the point here.
But, could Spirit's contracts be sold separately. After all, if one contract says "1 plane leased for $1M/year" and current market price is "1 plane leased for $2M/year", you could argue that such a contract has a $1M/year value.
Could such a contract be endorsed/sold to a third party? Of course, that means that Jet Blue would have to follow all of the stipulations of the contracts, so that the leaser does not suffer any perjudice.
This is more of a question about the principles at play than jurisdiction specific but, given the origin of the question, if there are different answers then the one closest to Spirit's jurisdiction would be better.
Disclaimer: this is not legal advice as I am not interested in buying Spirit's airplane contracts.

There may be provisions in the lease agreement for what happens if the lessee goes into administration or is dissolved.

Assignment
The rights under a contract can be assigned to a third-party unilaterally (unless explicitly excluded). That is, without needing the permission of the other party to the contract. But the obligations under a contract remain with the contracting party.
So, Spirit could assign the benefit of the lease - the use of the plane - but they would still remain liable for the payments and the planes would still be owned by the leasing company. Conversely, the leasing company could assign their benefits - the annual payments - but would still have to fulfil their obligations, except wait, their obligations are complete, they have already supplied the plane. This is why your mortgage company can assign your loan to another bank, but you can’t assign obligations to make the repayments.
Novation
With the agreement of all parties to a contract, one of them can be replaced fully by a third-party who takes on the rights and obligations.
Just buy the planes
If the business cannot be saved, the bankruptcy will proceed to liquidation and all Spirit’s assets, including the leases on the planes, will be sold to the highest bidder.
The leasing company will have to agree, but, as long as they get their money from the sale, that won’t be a problem.
